# Getting "value x is not a member of xyz"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I'm following along with the Water Pouring video in week 2 of the Functional Program Design in Scala course on Coursera.

My code is almost identical to Martin's.  It seems to compile just fine.  And I'm able to instantiate an instance of the class in my worksheet.

But when I inspect the object, some members are there, and some aren't.  I get an error "value initialPath is not a member of water.Pouring"

Here is my code:

```
class Pouring(val capacity : Vector[Int] ) {

  type State = Vector[Int]

  val initialState : State = capacity map ( x => 0 )

  // Moves
  trait Move {
    def change( state : State ) : State
  }
  case class Empty( glass: Int )        extends Move {
    def change( state: State ) = state updated( glass, 0 )
  }
  case class Fill( glass: Int )         extends Move {
    def change( state: State ) = state updated( glass, capacity( glass ) )
  }
  case class Pour( from: Int, to: Int ) extends Move {
    def change( state: State ) = {
      val amount = state(from) min (capacity(to) - state(to))
        state.updated( from, state(from) - amount )
             .updated( to,   state(to)   + amount )
    }
  }

  class Path(history: List[Move]) {
    def endState : State = (history foldRight initialState)(_ change _)
    def extend(move: Move) = new Path( move :: history )
    override def toString = (history.reverse mkString " ") + " => " + endState
  }

  val initialPath = new Path(Nil)

  val glasses = capacity.indices

  val moves =
    ( for ( g <- glasses ) yield Empty(g) ) ++
    ( for ( g <- glasses ) yield Fill(g) ) ++
    ( for ( from <- glasses ; to <- glasses if from != to ) yield Pour(from,to) )


  def from( paths: Set[Path] ): Stream[Set[Path]] =
    if ( paths.isEmpty ) Stream.empty
    else {
      val more = for {
        path <- paths
        move <- moves
      } yield path.extend( move )
      paths #:: from( more )
    }

  val pathSets = from(Set(initialPath))

}
```

My worksheet is simple enough:

```
object testing {
  val problem = new Pouring(Vector(4, 7))

  problem.initialState // works
  problem.glasses      // works
  problem.moves        // works
  problem.initialPath  // fails
  problem.pathSets     // fails
}
```

I don't get what's wrong.  The IDE (IntelliJ) auto-completed the member names, so why is it complaining that it is not a member?  Have I run into a Scala bug?  Or an IntelliJ bug?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your code works just fine. You paste it in the REPL. The problem is probably with IntelliJ which is known to have such behavior.

Comment: Thanks @pedrofurla - so how do I fix the problem with IntelliJ?

Comment: Use SBT: http://www.scala-sbt.org/

Comment: Or if you really mean it, look at IntelliJ's website on how to contribute, or the Scala plugin's website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere along the lines, the expected behavior changed.  Code as written in the video no longer works with the latest Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ.

All that was required was to remove the `object XXX { }` wrapper around the code, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If intelliJ is not showing the member properly one hack is to delete the .idea folder and reopen the project again in intelliJ. It might resolve the issue. If that does not work you might try invalidating cache of the intelliJ.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: Tried both, but to no avail.  Worse, suddenly after the latest update, I was getting NO output of any kind.

Comment: But I eventually found where someone else posted that if you remove the outer "object" definition, it works.  I did that, and now I'm up and running correctly.  Whew.